# error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong. My operator called operation is already a string.

> javac Arithmetic2.java

```
Arithmetic2.java:44: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        case '+' : { result = add; }
                             ^
Arithmetic2.java:45: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        case '-' : { result = sub; }
                             ^
Arithmetic2.java:46: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        case '*' : { result = mul; }
                             ^
Arithmetic2.java:47: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        case '/' : { result = div; }
                             ^
Arithmetic2.java:48: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        case '%' : { result = per; }
                             ^
5 errors
```

Arithmetic2.java

```
// Arithmetic2.java - This program performs arithmetic, ( +. -, *. /, % )     on two numbers
// Input:  Interactive.
// Output:  Result of arithmetic operation

import javax.swing.*;

public class Arithmetic2
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double numberOne, numberTwo;
    String numberOneString, numberTwoString;
    String operation;
    double result;

    numberOneString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number: ");
    numberOne = Double.parseDouble(numberOneString);
    numberTwoString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number: ");
    numberTwo = Double.parseDouble(numberTwoString);
    operation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an operator (+.-.*,/,%): ");

    // Call performOperation method here
    performOperation(numberOne, numberTwo, operation, result);

    System.out.format("%.2f",numberOne);
    System.out.print(" " + operation + " ");
    System.out.format("%.2f", numberTwo);
    System.out.print(" = ");
    System.out.format("%.2f", result);

    System.exit(0);

} // End of main() method.

// Write performOperation method here.
public static double performOperation(double numberOne, double numberTwo, String operation, double result) {
    double add = numberOne+numberTwo;
    double sub = numberOne-numberTwo;
    double mul = numberOne*numberTwo;
    double div = numberOne/numberTwo;
    double per = numberOne%numberTwo;

    switch(operation) {
        case '+' : { result = add; }
        case '-' : { result = sub; }
        case '*' : { result = mul; }
        case '/' : { result = div; }
        case '%' : { result = per; }
        default : { System.out.println("Invalid operator!"); }
    }
}
} // End of Arithmetic2 class.
```

Comment: Exactly like it says: you're trying to compare a `String` (`operation`) with a `char` (the switch cases). Change the `char` to a `String`, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [JOptionPane::showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) in most cases returns `String` (except the [one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) that requires lots of arguments to help it return a correct object type), it's better to use the `String` in the subsequent flow.

Simply change the `switch` cases quotation marks from `''` (char) to `""` (String). You don't need to change the method arguments.

```
switch(operation) {
    case "+" : { result = add; break; }
    case "-" : { result = sub; break; }
    case "*" : { result = mul; break; }
    case "/" : { result = div; break; }
    case "%" : { result = per; break; }
    default : { System.out.println("Invalid operator!"); break; }
}
```

Edit: Don't forget `break`s.

Comment: Yes this makes perfect sense. I dont know how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`operation` is a `String`, but your `case` statements all use `char` constants. Option 1: Change the `switch`, like

```
switch(operation.charAt(0))
```

Option 2: Change the `case` statements, like

```
switch(operation) {
    case "+" : { result = add; }
    case "-" : { result = sub; }
    case "*" : { result = mul; }
    case "/" : { result = div; }
    case "%" : { result = per; }
    default : { System.out.println("Invalid operator!"); }
}
```

However, in both cases the `{}` aren't meaningful and the `case` statements will **fall-through** - add breaks!

```
switch(operation) {
    case "+" : result = add; break;
    case "-" : result = sub; break;
    case "*" : result = mul; break;
    case "/" : result = div; break;
    case "%" : result = per; break;
    default : System.out.println("Invalid operator!"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the single quotes with double quotes, as Java interprets single quotes as a char, so your code would need to read:

```
switch(operation) {
    case "+" : {result = add; }  // and so on...

}
```

Hope that helps a little :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `operation` variable to a `char` type and it would work.

Or change the switch options to String by replacing the single quotes with double as it will change the options to `String`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `operation` is a string, but the error is telling you that `'+'` is *not* a string.

In Java, double quotes are for making a string literal, and single quotes are for making a char literal.  You are trying to compare a string to a char.

If you change `'+'` (and the rest of your `case` operands) to `"+"`, it should work.